# Mechanical energy conservation for different chosen systems

Tags: energy, gravity, energy-conservation, spring

I studied work-energy theorem and the equation for mechanical energy conservation yesterday. I’m not able to understand how to identify forces when choosing a system (which force is which).

This is how my textbook derived the equation for mechanical energy conservation, using the work-energy theorem : ($W$ is for *work*, $K$ for *kinetic energy*, $U$ for *potential energy*, $E$ for *mechanical energy*, $int$ for *internal forces*, $ext$ for *external forces*, $cons$ and $NC$ for *conservative* and *non-conservative forces*, respectively. And, $int_{cons}$ and $int_{NC}$ are for *internal conservative* and *internal non-conservative forces*, respectively)

$W_{total} = $$K_f$-$K_i$

($W_{int}$) + $W_{ext} = $$K_f$-$K_i$

(${W_{int}}_{cons}$ + ${W_{int}}_{NC}$) + $W_{ext}$ = $K_f$-$K_i$

(${W_{int}}_{NC}$) + $W_{ext}$  = $K_f$ - $K_i$ - (${W_{int}}_{cons}$)

(${W_{int}}_{NC}$) + $W_{ext}$  = $K_f$ - $K_i$ + $U_f$ - $U_i$

${W_{int}}_{NC}$ + $W_{ext}$ = $E_f$ - $E_i$

This is the equation. 
Now, I want to use this equation for this system. Initially the spring is at its natural length, the block stretches it to its elastic limit, by let’s say, $x$ units. I want to use the mechanical energy equation to find $x$. I choose the position that the block is at initially, as my reference level for zero gravitational potential energy and zero elastic potential energy.

[image]

I’m unable to decide which forces is which when choosing my system.

(1) First I choose the block as my system [image]

Now I use the equation : ${W_{int}}_{NC}$ + $W_{ext}$ = $E_f$ - $E_i$

There are no internal forces. Here, is it ok to treat gravity and the spring force as the external forces even though they are conservative forces? If I treat them as external forces, I get

$O$ + (-$\frac{1}{2}$$kx^2$ + $mgx$) = $0$ - $0$

This does get me the right answer, i.e, $x$ = $\frac{2mg}{k}$. But I’m not sure if I am doing it right. Initially, mechanical energy of the block is obviously zero. And $U_f$ of the block is still zero because I have chosen the block as my system, so I can’t claim that $U_f$ of the block is $-mgx$ because gravitational potential energy is the property of the block and the earth, not just the block alone, right?

(2) Similarly, now I choose the block and the spring as my system 
[image]

I use : ${W_{int}}_{NC}$ + $W_{ext}$ = $E_f$ - $E_i$

There are no internal non-conservative forces in the system I have chosen. And gravity is the external force, right? $E_i$ of the system is zero, and $U_f$ of the system (due to the spring) is $\frac{1}{2}$$kx^2$. $K_f$ of the system is zero as well.

$0$ + $(-mgx)$ = $\frac{1}{2}$$kx^2$ - $0$

Again, this gets me the right answer. But have I chosen my forces correctly for this system?

(3) This time around, I choose Earth and the block as my system. 
[image]

Now spring force is an external force, and there are no internal non-conservative forces acting on the system, because gravity is an **internal conservative force**. $E_i$ is zero, $U_f$ is $-mgx$, and $K_f$ is zero.

Using ${W_{int}}_{NC}$ + $W_{ext}$ = $E_f$ - $E_i$ gets me,

$0$ - $\frac{1}{2}$$kx^2$ = -$mgx$ - $0$

Once again I get the correct answer but have I identified the forces correctly?

(4) Finally, I chose all three (block, earth, spring) as my system. 
[image]

Now there are no external forces and no non-conservative forces, because gravity and spring force are **internal** but **conservative** forces. $E_i$ of the system is zero like always, and $E_f$ of the system is (-$mgx$ + $\frac{1}{2}$$kx^2$)

Using ${W_{int}}_{NC}$ + $W_{ext}$ = $E_f$ - $E_i$ , I get

$0$ + $0$ = (-$mgx$ + $\frac{1}{2}$$kx^2$) - $0$

I get the correct answer, but I still don’t know if I am identifying my forces correctly.

Have I made mistakes when identifying the forces for the different systems I have chosen? Please help me with it. I am not sure if I completely understand the equation : ${W_{int}}_{NC}$ + $W_{ext}$ = $E_f$ - $E_i$

Appreciate any help!

Comment: For future posts, note that you can just stick an entire equation between $ signs. You don't need to wrap each term in those signs. Try it out :)

Comment: @BioPhysicist thanks. I did not know that